# iOS app getting throttled from local searches

Tags: ios, mapkit, mklocalsearch

I am implementing autocomplete (one search per new character added) in an app that searches for addresses, and I keep getting `MKErrorDomain error 3`, which is `MKErrorLoadingThrottled`. This error, according to [Apple dev](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitConstantsReference/Reference/reference.html), occurs when

> The data was not loaded because data throttling is in effect. This
>   error can occur if an app makes frequent requests for data over a
>   short period of time.

I know exactly how many requests are being made, one for each new charachter in the search query (just like you would expect autocomplete to work). Sure, I am a fast typer, but being able to hit the limit after just 10 or 15 requests seems absurd. Looking at the following two source references, I do not understand why I keep getting throttled.

According to [Apple dev](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html):

> There are no request limits per app or developer ID, so well-written
>   apps that operate correctly should experience no problems. However,
>   throttling may occur in a poorly written app that creates an extremely
>   large number of requests.

and as James Howard [said at a WWDC:](http://asciiwwdc.com/2013/sessions/304)

> And the other thing I want to talk about is the Usage Limits on this
>   API.
>   So, I'm happy to announce that there's no application or developer
>   identifier wide usage limits.
>   So, if you have a app that has a lot of users and you want to do a lot
>   of requests, that's fine.
>
> It'll work.
>
> And the throttling that we do have is really just a first line of
>   defense against buggy apps.
>   So, if you put directions requests or local search requests in an
>   infinite loop, you've got a bug, eventually you're going to get
>   throttled.
>
> **But if you do something reasonable, you say oh, I'm going to just do
>   directions in response to user input and you know you can do a few of
>   those because we showed them that example.**
>
> Like we did two directions request in response to one user input,
>   that's fine.
>   But, you know if you're doing 10,000 every time the user taps on the
>   screen, then you're going to get throttled.
>   But, just keep it reasonable and you'll be fine.

Any ideas to why this is happening??

Comment: I wouldn't expect autocomplete to work like that. I'd expect an initial request and then to filter those results in-memory based on further input.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you are doing. Are you searching, or are you geocoding (i.e. turning a location into an address, or finding a location based on an address).

Comment: @quellish The first thing I mention is that it searches for addresses. Also, see the title of the question.

Comment: MKLocalSearch is for searching for *points of interest*. Businesses, etc. Geocoding is finding addresses, or turning addresses into locations. Your description of "searching for addresses" seems to describe geocoding rather than local search.

Comment: @quellish I did not know that. I was using MKLocalSearch and removing those with a business ID in order to get only addresses. I ended up using Google Places anyway. Thank you.

Comment: Actually on iOS 7 the limit seems to be 47 requests per minute.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Autocompletion requires a special APIs. MapKit doesn't offer such an interface. Just firing off dozens of requests to the normal search API causes a tremendous load.

You basically have two options:

1. Go with Google Places. They have a dedicated [Places Autocompletion API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete). There is even a complete library for iOS on [GitHub](https://github.com/chenyuan/SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete).
2. Reduce the number of requests, e.g. by only sending a request if the user has paused typing for 300ms and only if no earlier request is outstanding. But that's still no guarantee that Apple won't throttle your requests.

Comment: Option 2 seems to me logic and a must in any case.

Comment: Ended up using an Objective-C wrapper to Google Places, called SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete. Works great!

Comment: Option 2 still results in throttling, at least on my simulator.

Comment: Mapkit now has https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mklocalsearchcompleter as of iOS 9.3.  Pretty sure that was introduced after this original post

Answer (score 4):

`MKLocalSearch` is primarily intended for finding points of interest (businesses, etc.) within a map's bounds. CLGeocoder is for structured address and location lookups.

The [CLGeocoder documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html) specifies that CLGeocoder requests *are* rate limited, and the documentation provides guidance on how to be a good citizen.

Of particular note is the first item in the guidelines: "Send at most one request for any user action". This should be applied to `MKLocalSearch` as well - if you have multiple requests in flight at the same time, you are VERY likely to get throttled.

This is actually pretty easy to implement: Before a new `MKLocalSearchRequest` is sent, cancel any pending requests. This makes a lot of sense for implementing autocomplete like you describe: if the user is entering the 4th character, you probably don't need the request or response for the 3rd character.

Comment: Also  CLGeocoder has different results in compare of  MKLocalSearch

Answer (score 2):

Run your app in the Time Profiler Instrument an see how many calls to that method are being made when you type.

Comment: This problem happened to me recently. It turned out that my code was thrashing thereby making multiple api calls.  So, check your code and clean it up.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just wrote Helper on **Swift** to help make suggests with Apple MapKit API. It's call search request when user stop typing request. https://github.com/ArniDexian/GeocodeHelper

The usage is pretty simply:

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    GeocodeHelper.shared.decode(searchText.trimmed(), completion: { [weak self](places) -> () in
        self?.dataSource.locations = places
        self?.tableView.reloadData()
        return
        })
}
```