# Is there any Usage Limit to the calls of MKDirections API in an iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, mapkit

As the title. Is there any daily limit or peak frequency, to calls of `MKDirections`?

Comment: Look at the constant: `MKErrorLoadingThrottled`.

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505097/ios-app-getting-throttled-from-local-searches