# Searching for addresses using MapKit on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mapkit, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar where the user types in a string (e.g. an address) and it should suggestion some addresses.

So let's say I am within Apple's Maps App, and I type in "New Yo" I'll get the city of New York + some local search results.

It seems like Apple's using a mixture between a MKLocalSearch and a forward geocoding.

Now If I search the docu, it clearly states that I must not use the CLGeoCoding for searching addresses but I should use the MKLocalSearch.

So what is the best approach here? MKLocalsearch is actually for finding spots within a near distance to the user or am I wrong?

By the way, I am using Swift :D
Thanks

Comment: If you are trying to implement auto-complete or incremental search, MapKit and CoreLocation do not currently support this.  I have found MKLocalSearch to be very limited and "unproductive" even for what it is supposed to do.  For auto-complete, the Google Places Autocomplete API is excellent but may require you to switch to using Google Maps only to comply with the licensing.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505097/ios-app-getting-throttled-from-local-searches.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to search locations use CLGeocoder.
(the downside is that apple limits the amount of api calls, so you probably won't get a bunch of results when you type "new yo..." for example, but it does the job).

MKLocalSearch, on the other hand, is specifically designed for Mapkit.

*"MKLocalSearch allows developers to find nearby points of interest within a geographic region."*

I'm not sure how much map kit integration you are doing, but if you are just trying to allow the user to search for locations, the above should help.

I should also note that google has a [geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) that you can use if you aren't satisfied with CLGeocoder.

Comment: So this means there's actually no really possibility to get a suggestion list for addresses while the user is typing? I mean the LocalSearch does what it says, it searches within a region, but if I want to search for an address within another city, I am out of luck?

Comment: You can search for an address within another city using CLGeocoder (and it will work), but you won't get the autocomplete suggestions you are looking for.